# printing colored string in cpp

Tags: c++, printing, colors, cout

I have a problem in colorizing a special string or character in cpp.
I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define red "\x1B[31m"
#define reset "\033[0m"
#define blue "\x1B[34m"
#define green "\x1B[32m"
#define yellow "\x1B[33m"

int main()
{
cout << red << "red text" << reset << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to print **red text** by red color.It works in online compilers.
But in ( dev c++ ) and code::blocks ,it is output :

```
←[31mred text←[0m
```

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: Try `"\033[31m"`

Comment: it also depends on the terminal. C++ itself doesnt know about colored output

Comment: dev-cpp is a Windows IDE. The codes you're using are known to work, for example, on typical Linux consoles. Allegedly they also work on Windows 10.   See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score -2):

Might be easier and more portable to use the Windows API.

`SET_FOREGROUND_COLOR .. SET_BACKGROUND_COLOR ..` etc.

If you use the Windows header you can easily find workable code to implement it.

Comment: how is a windows specific API "more portable" ?

Comment: If OP wants portability they might as well use {fmt} : https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#terminal-color-and-text-style